# Compare and sort strings in multiple languages

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort in JS strings alphabetically. In English sorting is quite easy:

```
sortArr.sort( function ( a , b ) {
  return a > b ? 1 : -1;
} );
```

However the app I am working on will be translated to i.a. Arabic, Chinese, German, Russian and a few others. What I can see that even for non ASCII characters the results seems not to be right.

I found `Intl.Collator().compare` according to docs:

> The Intl.Collator object is a constructor for collators, objects that enable language sensitive string comparison.

However, it's not supported by Safari and most of the mobile browsers.

Is there any other solution I can use?

**EDIT**

There is `String.prototype.localeCompare()` but browser support is not good enough too.

Comment: There was a polyfill attempt, but polyfilling `Intl.Collator` is rather unreasonable: https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/ Judging from this bug on the webkit tracker, there seems to be some progress on this issue though: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147601 For many cases, doing server-side sorting might be a viable solution as well.

Comment: @nils Ok I see that it has npm package, I'll look closer. Thanks

Comment: Node.js support should be there. I just tried `Intl.Collator()` in the node repl, it seems to work.

Comment: Given spotty browser support, it seems your options are two: [1] do it on the server-side (may have "performance" issues) or [2] find or write your own client-side collation function for each language you need (may have "ugh" issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.
Every language has its own alphabetic order. For example
Russian has the letter 'с' in a different order than Turkish.
Your only option imo is to use the [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) when possible (browsers that support it). Afaik there aren't any other ready-to-go libraries or object that you can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Most modern browsers now support `Intl.Collator` as of 2020. Even IE11 supports some of its features (although not all). Intl.Collator will sort in almost any language you can think of (certainly more than I can think of) and has numerous options for customizing sorting by accent marks, capitalization, etc.

See this Mozilla Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#Browser_compatibility

This guy gives a really good tutorial on how to use it.
https://dev.to/aumayeung/comparing-non-english-strings-with-javascript-collators-57bf